# How to set shape size dynamically in Joint JS?

Tags: jointjs

I am new to Joint JS and I am not able to dynamically set width and height properties of below element:

```
var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({

    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
});
```

Is there any way to set those properties dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Try this function:

```
rect.resize(200, 60);
```

You read more about it [here](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:resize).